# AlertDialog Doesn't Appear on GoogleMap. Panic

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog, android-mapview, touch-event

I'm new to android but i have managed to follow a few tutorials to get me started.. What i want to do is make an Alert Dialog Box with three button appear once the user has touch down on the screen for more than 2(seconds) The problem i'm encountering is the ALERTDIALOG Box does not appear on the map when i initiate it.. i dont get any errors ? so can some one please help me.

Below is my Code....

```
    long start;
    long stop;

    //reference map from citymap.xml file
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvMain);

    // Enable zoom features 
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    //Declaring the instance Interaction 
    Interact t = new Interact();

    //declaring a list of overlays
    List<Overlay> overlayList = map.getOverlays();

    // interact t in to overlay list.
    overlayList.add(t);

    class Interact extends Overlay {    
        public boolean OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m){
        // initiating motion event action down
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // set start time
            start = e.getEventTime();

        }
        // Initiating motion event action up: when the user stops on touch event
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            // set end time 
            stop = e.getEventTime();
        }
        // calculating the time to project an alert dialog 
        if (stop > 1500){
            Toast.makeText(CityMap.this, "toast meee", 50000).show();
            //perform an action, create alert dialog box
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CityMap.this).create();
            builder.setTitle("Select an Option");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Place pint Point", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
builder.create();
            builder.show();
            return true;
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: Try to specify z-index and background color for alert dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up a bit the last if statement. Try returning false the second time.

Check out mine:

```
if (stop - start > 1500) {
            // perform some action
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Pick an option");
            alert.setMessage("Pick an option dude!");

            alert.setButton("Place a pin",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

For @Pepys: This method is deprecated. You should use

```
alert.setPositiveButton("your text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {...
}});
```